How to connect public web app to private internal resources
We have a Public web app which is acting as the front end and it should be accessible for users publicly, and we have some resources like storage accounts, Search indexers which used by web app to query data and give output to the users. Our goal is to make web app publicly accessible in the same time it should have internal private access to resources like storage accounts etc. What is the recommended way to do this?
We tried using the private endpoint approach but stuck at the point when we enabled private end points web app also need to be private not public, which our goal is to keep the web app publicly accessible

To keep your web app public while accessing private resources, use VNet Integration for the web app without enabling private endpoints for the web app itself. Configure Private Endpoints for storage and other resources, and ensure proper DNS settings to resolve these private endpoints within the VNet. @Chamara

One approach to make a public web app accessible while keeping internal private access to resources like storage accounts is to use a private endpoint. However, enabling private endpoints for the web app also makes it private, which is not the desired outcome.

Another option is to use a public URL to access the application both inside and outside the virtual network, and secure traffic to the public endpoint with a network security group. This allows the web app to remain publicly accessible while still restricting access to internal resources. Another option is to use Azure Virtual Network (VNet) and configure a private endpoint for the static web app, which allows the app to be integrated into the VNet and only accessible from machines within the VNet.

@VinayB Thanks for valuable reply. will check that option
